# codeigniter don't get the right value using for loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm struggling getting the right values in of a for loop.

here is the data that i pass from the controller to the view

```
 $data['moisString'] = $moisString;
 //result of var_dump
 var_dump($data['moisString'] );
        array (size=3)
           0 => string 'Janvier' (length=7)
           1 => string 'Février' (length=8)
           2 => string 'Mars' (length=4)

 $data['year'] = $year;
 //result of var_dump
 var_dump($data['year'] );
        array (size=3)
           0 => int 2014
           1 => int 2014
           2 => int 2014
```

in my view i have a form_dropdown and i want to obtain something like:

```
****************
* Janvier 2014 *
* Février 2014 *
* Mars 2014    *
****************
```

here is the view:

```
echo form_open('suivrePaiement/view', 'method="get"');

$month = array();
$annee = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($moisString); $i++) {
     $month[] = $moisString[$i];
     $annee[]= $year[$i];
           foreach ($ficheFrais as $mois) {
           $options[$mois->mois] = $month[$i]." ".$annee[$i];
           }
    }   

echo form_dropdown('mois', $options, $this->input->get('mois'), 'class="btn btn-default  

dropdown-toggle"');

echo form_hidden('visiteur', set_value('visiteur', $this->input->get('visiteur')));
echo form_submit('', 'Envoyer', 'class="btn btn-info"');

echo form_close();
```

but this is what i get:

```
*************
* Mars 2014 *
* Mars 2014 *
* Mars 2014 *
*************
```

does anyone has a solution to this? thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach should be done after the loop is done.

The last loop is 3 for example .. so all options will get the same `$i`. So you are overwriting the `$options` three times in your code.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($moisString); $i++) {
     $month[] = $moisString[$i];
     $annee[]= $year[$i];
}

$counter = 0;
foreach ($ficheFrais as $mois) {
    $options[$mois->mois] = $month[$counter]." ".$annee[$counter++];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_map to clear your hand.

put this on your controller:

```
$options = array_map("set_option", $data['moisString], $data['year]);
$data['dropdown'] =  form_dropdown('mois', $options, $this->input->get('mois'), 'class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"');
```

and create a function

```
function set_option($moisString, $year)
{
return $moisString . ' ' . $year;
}
```

look this reference [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

in your view just echo $dropdown;